# ¿Por qué tengo una columna adicional con TreeView?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy creando una interfaz gráfica para una aplicación de chat (que funciona por consola actualmente).

El problema que tengo es que al usar el widget `ttk.TreeView` y crear 3 columnas me aparecen 4 y una de ellas vacía (la última). Os dejo una captura de pantalla y el código. ¿Cómo podría eliminar esa "Columna vacía" de mi `TreeView`?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí os dejo el código:

```py
def GUI():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Chat - RuDaHee")


    frame = Frame(root).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    chat = ttk.Treeview(frame, height=10, columns=("#0","#1", "#2"), selectmode="extended")
    chat.heading('#0', text='Hora', anchor=CENTER)
    chat.heading("#1", text="Usuario", anchor=CENTER)
    chat.heading("#2", text="Mensaje", anchor=W)
    chat.column("#0", stretch=NO, width=80)
    chat.column("#1", stretch=NO, width=80)
    chat.column("#2", stretch=NO, width=380)

    chat.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")


    escribirMensaje = Entry(frame, width=87).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", padx=10, pady=10)
    enviarMensaje = Button(frame, text="Enviar").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)
    root.mainloop()


GUI()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La primera columna es siempre el índice de la tabla del `Tree` y por defecto su identificador es siempre `'#0'`. Al asignar tres columnas mediante el argumento `columns` creas tres columnas **más el índice**, por lo que aparentemente ves 4).

Una solución es pasar a `columns` solo los identificadores de tus dos columnas sin incluir `#0`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def gui():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Chat - RuDaHee")

    frame = tk.Frame(root).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    chat = ttk.Treeview(
        frame,
        height=10,
        columns=("#1", "#2"),
        selectmode="extended",
        )
    chat.heading('#0', text='Hora', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    chat.heading("#1", text="Usuario", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    chat.heading("#2", text="Mensaje", anchor=tk.W)
    chat.column("#0", stretch=tk.NO, width=80)
    chat.column("#1", stretch=tk.NO, width=80)
    chat.column("#2", stretch=tk.NO, width=380)

    chat.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

    escribir_mensaje = tk.Entry(frame, width=87)
    escribir_mensaje.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", padx=10, pady=10)
    enviar_mensaje = tk.Button(frame, text="Enviar")
    enviar_mensaje.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

    # Ejemplo de insercion de datos
    chat.insert("", 'end', text="11:15", values=("Fulanito","¡Hola!"))

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui()
```

Otra opción es que ignores el propio índice no mostrándolo (`show="headings"`) y crees tres columnas (recuerda que `#0` está reservado para el índice, aunque no lo muestres sigue ahí):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def gui():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Chat - RuDaHee")

    frame = tk.Frame(root).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    chat = ttk.Treeview(
        frame,
        height=10,
        columns=("#1", "#2", "#3"),
        selectmode="extended",
        show="headings"
        )

    chat.heading('#1', text='Hora', anchor=tk.CENTER)
    chat.heading("#2", text="Usuario", anchor=tk.CENTER)
    chat.heading("#3", text="Mensaje", anchor=tk.W)
    chat.column("#1", stretch=tk.NO, width=80)
    chat.column("#2", stretch=tk.NO, width=80)
    chat.column("#3", stretch=tk.NO, width=380)

    chat.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

    escribir_mensaje = tk.Entry(frame, width=87)
    escribir_mensaje.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", padx=10, pady=10)
    enviar_mensaje = tk.Button(frame, text="Enviar")
    enviar_mensaje.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

    # Ejemplo de inserción de datos
    chat.insert("", 'end', values=("11:15","Fulanito","¡Hola!"))

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui()
```

Ahora bien, **la forma rellenar la tabla varía**. En el primer caso la `hora` (columna índice) debes pasarla al argumento `text` de `TreeView.insert`, mientra `usuario` y `mensaje` los pasas mediante el argumento `values`. En el segundo caso, los tres datos los pasa mediante la tupla de `values`, ignorando el índice, ya que los tres son columnas.